# Como posso alinhar o segundo card para a direita?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Quero alinhar o segundo card (estou usando o Bootstrap) na direita, como posso fazer isto?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                     <div class="card card-certificado" style="width: 18rem;">
                         <img class="card-img-top" src="imagens/certificadoa1.png" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
                         <div class="card-body">
                             <h5 class="card-title text-center">Certificado A1</h5>
                             <p class="card-text text-center">
                                 O Certificado A1 (e-CNPJ A1) é gerado em software, que fica instalado em um computador da empresa e, geralmente, tem menor custo ao portador.
                                 Porém, sua validade é sempre de 1 ano. Ao final do prazo, é preciso renovar novamente e pagar os valores referentes.
                             </p>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-6">
                     <div class="card card-certificado" style="width: 18rem;">
                         <img class="card-img-top" src="imagens/certificadoa1.png" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
                         <div class="card-body">
                             <h5 class="card-title text-center">Certificado A1</h5>
                             <p class="card-text text-center">
                                 O Certificado A1 (e-CNPJ A1) é gerado em software, que fica instalado em um computador da empresa e, geralmente, tem menor custo ao portador.
                                 Porém, sua validade é sempre de 1 ano. Ao final do prazo, é preciso renovar novamente e pagar os valores referentes.
                             </p>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim com a propriedade `Float` do `CSS` que funciona no `Bootstrap`

```
        <div class="col-lg-6">
             <div class="card card-certificado float-left" style="width: 18rem;">
                 <img class="card-img-top" src="imagens/certificadoa1.png" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title text-center">Certificado A1</h5>
                     <p class="card-text text-center">
                         O Certificado A1 (e-CNPJ A1) é gerado em software, que fica instalado em um computador da empresa e, geralmente, tem menor custo ao portador.
                         Porém, sua validade é sempre de 1 ano. Ao final do prazo, é preciso renovar novamente e pagar os valores referentes.
                     </p>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-6">
             <div class="card card-certificado float-right" style="width: 18rem;">
                 <img class="card-img-top" src="imagens/certificadoa1.png" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title text-center">Certificado A1</h5>
                     <p class="card-text text-center">
                         O Certificado A1 (e-CNPJ A1) é gerado em software, que fica instalado em um computador da empresa e, geralmente, tem menor custo ao portador.
                         Porém, sua validade é sempre de 1 ano. Ao final do prazo, é preciso renovar novamente e pagar os valores referentes.
                     </p>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Float com certeza foi a única coisa que não pensei, kkkkk. Não sou chegado a ele. Enfim, funcionou, valeu ai por resolver essa dúvida simples kkkkk.

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode usar no card a classe `ml-auto`, isso vai fazer o `card` colar na direita da `col`, pois ele vai dar uma margem a esquerda do tamanho do "espaço vazio", não precisa usar `float`, que eu não indico nesse caso...

Vc pode ler aqui na documentação oficial como fazer margens automáticas no Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins

Vc tem que executar em Página toda para ter um melhor resultado, e tb tem que pensar como quer tratar isso em telas pequenas...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="card card-certificado" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="imagens/certificadoa1.png" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center">Certificado A1</h5>
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        O Certificado A1 (e-CNPJ A1) é gerado em software, que fica instalado em um computador da empresa e, geralmente, tem menor custo ao portador.
                        Porém, sua validade é sempre de 1 ano. Ao final do prazo, é preciso renovar novamente e pagar os valores referentes.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="card card-certificado ml-auto" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="imagens/certificadoa1.png" alt="Imagem de capa do card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center">Certificado A1</h5>
                    <p class="card-text text-center">
                        O Certificado A1 (e-CNPJ A1) é gerado em software, que fica instalado em um computador da empresa e, geralmente, tem menor custo ao portador.
                        Porém, sua validade é sempre de 1 ano. Ao final do prazo, é preciso renovar novamente e pagar os valores referentes.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: eu tentei usar ml-auto, e ocorreu quebra de linha.

Comment: @FelipeMoreira a quebra de linha e por causa do Grid de Cols do Bootstrap e não por causa da margem ou alinhamento